# Is there a term that refers to the distance of an object from the mean?

Tags: terminology, distance

I am trying to rephrase this sentence:

> I will compare the difference between the deviation of the student's midterm exam mark in this class from the class average with the deviation of the marks given to his other midterm exams from their respective class averages.

**Is there an `alternative_word` that could be used to replace "the deviation of the student's midterm exam mark in this class from the class average"?** My sentence would be less awkward if it read:

> I will compare the `alternative_word` of the student's mid-term exam mark with the `alternative_word` of his other mid-term exam marks.

Comment: "NSFW" means what exactly? Not Safe For Work? Confirmation of this may be useful for those not well-versed in internet slang. Thanks.

Comment: You will compare the difference ... to what?  Or will you just compare the deviations (as I suspect), which would enable you to get rid of "the difference between", thereby removing one layer of indirection from the sentence.

Comment: @Graeme Walsh, NSFW, you got it.

Comment: @jbowman for this student, her mid-term exam mark in question is unusually close to the class average, the distance between that mark and the class average is being compared to the distance between her average mark (from her other classes) and the mean of the class averages (from the other classes). In this case, she was in the center of the curve for the exam in question, but is usually two or three SDs above the mean. I'm trying to say, 'statistics show her marks are usually exceptional , her mark for this exam was unexceptional. That's weird for her.'

Comment: Deviation is commonly used. I suppose you might say "residual" if you specified what the implied model was a residual for (but you wouldn't say 'residual from the class mean').

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks Glen, could you give me an example of how'd you use residual in a sentence?

Comment: As I said you have to define it first. So something like "If we define an individual's residual to be the difference of their score from the overall mean, ($y_i-\bar y$), then we could compare the residual of the student's mid-term exam mark with the residual of his other marks"

Comment: However, if, as it seems in the comments, you want to compare how many standard deviations above the typical exam score the student is across different exams, you might do better to discuss *z-scores* (also called [standard scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score)).  If the student's typical exam is 3 sd's above the class mean, their typical z-score will be **3**.

Comment: You'd then have a sentence where you define their z-score (presumably you're doing it in terms of the class mean and sd for that particular test), followed by a sentence like "I will compare the student's mid-term z-score with their z-score on other tests". (I could probably collect all this up into an answer if this information is of any use.)